# Ctrl + Arrows: What algorithm or standard?

Tags: javascript

Is there some agreed upon algorithm of what is supposed to happen when, in a text editor or text editing field, the user presses Ctrl + Left-Arrow or Ctrl + Right-Arrow? I noticed the behavior in Chrome's text box, and Windows Notepad, for instance, aren't the same; the "jump to the last/ next bit" pattern is similar but not the same.

I'm looking for this info to emulate the behavior in my own Chrome/JavaScript-based text editor, as I'm not happy with how Chrome handles this at times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Standard action would be, jump to the next non-whitespace block of text in either direction (and as you noted this can depend on context of 'non-whitespace block')

Answer (score 1):

This is more than a browser-specific inconsistency, it's different across OSes. On Mac OS, Ctrl + Left/Right/Up/Down switches to a different Space (desktop), so you might not want to use this as an important keybinding if you want to serve Mac users as well.

*This is more about the keybinding than the algorithm, I just wanted to throw that out there. :)*

Comment: To clarify, Mac OS uses Alt + arrow for the same functionality.

Answer (score 1):

You should be platform-specific if necessary.  Linux & windows jump to the next word, and they select if also shifted.